# Handling keyboard events in UWP apps without Controls

Tags: uwp, keyboard-events

I'm working on a UWP app, which doesn't really have any controls that come with pre-built keyboard handling — it's a big tree of `Grid`s, and among them an `InkCanvas`, a `Win2D`, a regular `Canvas`, an `Image`, etc.

I've declared `KeyDown` and `PreviewKeyDown` handlers on my `Page`, but they are not invoked when I press a button in the basic setup.

I found out that I can call `Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` from my page, and then I receive key events, but only until I give focus to (click) the `InkCanvas` for example.

Then I found the section [Keyboard alternatives to pointer actions and events for specific control elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/accessibility/keyboard-accessibility#keyboard-alternatives-to-pointer-actions-and-events-for-specific-control-elements) in the documentation. It suggests to set `IsTabStop` on my own custom controls, or to wrap everything in a `<Button>`.

The latter kinda works, I can wrap my root `Grid` in a `Button` and then the `KeyDown` fires every time, no matter which element I've last given focus.
This just feels completely wrong, and it also creates some visual 'artifacts'. (It draws a button around everything...)

`IsTabStop` also works, but then I need to start wrapping everything in custom controls (e.g. the `Image`). It doesn't seem to 'inherit' down the tree.

Is there any best practice around this? Handling any keypress in my app shouldn't be so hard, should it?

Comment: did you try `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event?

Comment: @Muzib That seems to work! Do you want to provide this as an answer, maybe with some additional information what that is, why it might be a good (or bad) idea to use it and a link to some further reading?

Comment: if you haven't yet, go through this doc for better understanding of keyboard input in a Contol : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-events

Comment: it's not about `CoreWindow` Keyborad events though